# I can't disable back button from NavigationBar with Router

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I can't delete back button from Navigation Bar in Router.

In old versions of router the problem was solved with 2 different scene section. But in the new version of router we can't create 2 different scene. I have a login screen when user enters necessary part it goes another screen. But i can't disable back navigation bar.

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    //<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Router>
      <Scene key="kimlik">
        <Scene key="loginScreen" component={LoginForm} title="Giriş Ekranı" />
        <Scene
        key="studentsList"
        component={StudentsList} title="Öğrenci Liste"

        />
      </Scene>
    </Router>
    //</View>
  );
};

________________________________________________
in action file i call:

const loginSuccess = (dispatch, user) => {
  dispatch({
    type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
    payload: user
  });
  Actions.studentsList();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I changed the version.
Go >> package.json file

Write old version: "react-native-router-flux": "^3.40.1",